# node joined successfully to master node, but got error when kubectl get nodes "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused"

Tags: kubernetes, centos8

I'm using two virtual machine with operating system Centos 8

master-node:

- `kubeadm init`

node-1:

- `kubeadm join`

`node-1` joined successfully, and got the result run `"kubectl get nodes"`.
but running `kubectl get nodes` got response `"The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"`

I've checked my config using command `kubectl config view` and I got a result:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters: null
contexts: null
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: null
```

I've  `ls /etc/kubernetes/` and it show `kubelet.conf` only

Comment: Are you running kubectl command from master node or worker node?

Comment: That problem I encountered running on worker node

Comment: kubectl configs don't get replicated to other nodes when "kubeadm joining" them. Do you need it to work from worker node? If so you can copy the config from master node to worker node and use it. Most of the time you don't want to store k8s admin credentials on worker nodes where applications are running for security reasons.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: What? Does `kubectl get nodes` work on master node or not?

Comment: @Matt, I get it now, this make it clear I think, `kubectl configs don't get replicated to other nodes when kubeadm joining`, because I'm expecting to get the list of nodes on worker node?

Comment: What I mean is that when you run kubeadm init, kubeadm generates admin config/credentials on mater node. When you are joining (kubeadm join ...) kubeadm is not placing any admin credentials on the worker node. If you want it there you need to copy it from master to worker manually (or create a new ones). Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see you are trying to use kubectl on worker node after successfull `kubeadm join`.

`kubeadm init` is genereting kubeadmin credentials/config files that are used to connect to the cluster and you were expecting that `kubeadm join` will also create simmilar credentials so you can run kubectl commands from worker node. `kubeadm join` command is not placing any admin credentials on worker nodes (where applications are running; for security reasons).

If you want it there you need to copy it from master to worker manually (or create a new ones).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the writing, once `kubeadm init` is completed the master node is initialized and components are set.
Running `kubeadm join` on worker node would join this node to previous master.

After this step if you're running `kubectl get nodes` on master and encountering the above mentioned issue then its because cluster config is missing for kubectl.
The default config will be `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` which can set to environmental variables with key as `KUBECONFIG`.
Or simplest way would be to copy this file into .kube folder.

`cp -f /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf ~/.kube/config`